# Vue - Form component with child input component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent component (form container):

```
<template lang="pug">
    form
       MyCustomInput(v-on:emitMethod="parentEmitMethod")
         button(@click.prevent="send")
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    ...
    data () {
      return {
        inputValue: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submit () {
        //submit logic
      },
      parentEmitMethod (arg) {
       this.inputValue = arg
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and child component (input component - MyCustomInput)

```
<template lang="pug">
    input(v-model="inputValChild")
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    ...
    data () {
      return {
        inputValChild: ''
      }
    },
    watch: {
      inputValChild: {
         handle () : {
            this.$emit('emitMethod', this.inputValChild)
         }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

For communication child component -> parent component (send input value to form) I use `$emit`. It works great.

Now I would like to after `submit ()` method (in parent component) clear `inputValChild` data (in child component). What are the best practices for this?

Comment: Implement `v-model` support in the child component and clear the value in the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use dynamic props to update the child from the parent.  From their [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props):

> Whenever the data is updated in the parent, it will also flow down to the child

Something like:

```
<template lang="pug">
    form
       MyCustomInput(v-bind:inputValChild="inputValue" v-on:emitMethod="parentEmitMethod")
         button(@click.prevent="send")
</template>
```

And then declare `inputValChild` as a prop in your child component.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
handle () : {
  this.$emit('emitMethod', {
    param: this.inputValChild,
    callback: this.clearNow)
  }
```

And in the parent component I would simply call "callback()" after finishing.
The method clearNow would do the job in the child's component. But there are also other ways. Most important that you keep it consistent in the project and do not mix everything.